# Remotely Install an Application from a FileShare using WMI

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wmi, remote-execution

So far my code will start a process (Install an application) with command line arguments on a target computer and wait for the process to finish, IF I copy the install files to that computer.

My goal now is to:

1. Start a process with command line arguments (Install an application) on the remote computer.
2. NOT copy the files to the remote computer. The installer files will be located on a network share that both the sender computer and the remote computer have access to.
3. Wait for the process to finish.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
    private void StartAppAction(string PCName, string Params)
        {   
            //Example of Params \\Server\Folder\Application.EXE /s 

            ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();
            conn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            conn.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default;
            conn.EnablePrivileges = true;
            ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", PCName), conn);

            try
            {
                manScope.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            ObjectGetOptions objOpt = new ObjectGetOptions();
            ManagementPath manPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
            ManagementClass manClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, manPath, objOpt);
            ManagementBaseObject inParams = manClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
            inParams["CommandLine"] = Params;
            ManagementBaseObject outParams = manClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);

            string query = String.Format("SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 3 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND TargetInstance.ProcessID = '{0}'", outParams["ProcessId"].ToString());

            string scope = @"\\" + PCName + @"\root\CIMV2";

            EventWatcherOptions evOp = new EventWatcherOptions(null, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), 1);
            ManagementEventWatcher manWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query, evOp);
            try
            {
                ManagementBaseObject watcher = manWatch.WaitForNextEvent();
                var ID = ((ManagementBaseObject)watcher["TargetInstance"]);                
                //Process Ended
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to watch for the remote process to finish");
            }
        }
```